# Issue with the resize function while performing thresholding in opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I am looking to implement a project of computer vision in which I am having issues with the resize function while I am thresholding an image for further processing.

I have already tried various solutions provided on internet regarding this problem but none of them is working for my case. I have even tried to update the version of my opencv library but this has also not given any fruitful results.

#### Code, which results in an error:

```
threshold_eye = cv2.resize(threshold_eye, None, fx=5, fy=5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

#### Error:

> `cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3718: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'`

I am expecting, if someone can guide me about how can I solve this error or if there is any alternative method to perform the same task which I want to perform.

Comment: You can use the imutils library, `pip install imutils`. To resize `resized = imutils.resize(threshold_eye, width=300)`

Answer (score 0):

in the line:

**threshold_eye = cv2.resize(threshold_eye, None, fx=5, fy=5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)**
second parameter of function is "dsize" i.e output size.

I see that you have written "None" instead mention output image size for e.g op_dim = (width, height).

That should work.